# mysql query not recieving proper response... or something

Tags: php, mysql

alrighty so what i want to do should be clear by the code below,
for each row i want to run the code with their, if header is 0, run the first if statement, if it's 1 run the second.

Problem is, it doesn't matter what i set it to, it always runs the second if statement thinking header is always 1, even when it isn't.

to test i added echo (int)$row['header'] to the second if statement, and for every row, it echoed 1.

Anyone have any clue on how i can make it do what i want?

Thanks for the help

my php code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LeftMenu_items");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if ((int)$row['header'] = 0)
    {
        // echos value is on or not
        echo "<tr><td class='LeftMenu'><a href='" . $row['url'] . "'><b>" . $row['text'] . "</b></a></td></tr>\n";
    }
    else if ((int)$row['header'] = 1)
    {
        // header
        echo "<tr><td class='LeftMenu'>" . (int)$row['header'] . "<b>" . $row['text'] . "</b></td></tr>\n"; 
    }
    else echo "error displaying url";
```

My table looks like this:

```
structure:
id  int 
text    text    
url text    
Header  tinyint 

data:
1   Home    http://drudexflash.com/ 1
2   test1   http://text.com/    0
3   ttt blahz   1
4   nullnull    ass 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning a variable rather than comparing.

```
if((int)$row['header'] = 0)
```

should be

```
if ((int)$row['header'] == 0)
```

This isn't an uncommon bug, so what I sometimes do is switch the order of the value and variable, just to make it clear that I'm comparing vs assigning.

Example:

```
if (0 = (int)$row['header']) // even if you don't catch this as incorrect
                             // php will throw a 'parse error'
if (0 == (int)$row['header']) // correct, no error
```

Some useful documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: That's at least one problem with this approach.

Comment: Hmmh, it works but now i'm also getting "Notice: Undefined index: /path/"

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: /path/` is probably coming from a different part of your code. You don't appear to be accessing any index like that in this block.

Comment: @user1071461 - Look, doing `if (this = that)` is "assignment", not comparison; it is *not* equivalent to `if (this == that)` (note the double quotes). When you use one `=`, you're setting a variable, more than one, a comparison. This depends on the language if it's more than two `=`, as well (`truthyness` and all).

Comment: Whoops, nevermind, the name was "Header" instead of "header".. i shouldn't be doing this at 4 am :P It works perfectly now, thanks ^^